# QGIS Field Calculator Aggregation with a intersect query

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing

I have point (manholes) and line (sewer main) datasets and want attributes from the points at both ends of the line.

If I run the following after I install RefFunctions in field calc on the line

```
geomintersects('Sewer_MH_Test','RL_of_Lid')
```

I get the value I need from the start of the line (3.78). How do I get the value at the end (3.75) into a new column? Is there some aggregator to use?
[image]

---

Based on [@Taras' answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329302/115) I have been trying the following but it keeps crashing.

```
WITH start_data AS (
SELECT l.GID_New AS line_id_start, p.US_IL AS x
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
),

end_data AS (
SELECT l.GID_New AS line_id_end, p.DS_IL AS y
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(end_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
)

SELECT l.*, start_data.x, end_data.y
FROM lines AS l
JOIN start_data ON l.GID_New = line_id_start
JOIN end_data ON l.GID_New=line_id_end
```

This shows the output I want...
[image]

The test data is only about 20 lines and points - it can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rUV_pAaevs9vATbIsgc9QJvvziRygGN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is your point dataset snapped to the line dataset or it is somewhere nearby?

Comment: It's snapped to the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can user the aggregate expression for that, something like:

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'point_layer',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=fieldname_pointlayer,
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry,
geometry(@parent))
)
```

for labeling the line layer. If the point is not intersecting the polyline - like Taras pointed out in his comment - you can add a buffer around the point geometry: $geometry is the point geometry and geometry(@parent) is the polyline geometry.

Comment: I tried but get an error <<Eval Error: Could not calculate aggregate for: RL_of_Lid>> when using <<aggregate(
layer:= 'Sewer_MH_Test', aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=RL_of_Lid,
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry,
geometry(@parent))
)>> . I want to either create one field in the lines with RL values delimited or multiple fields with the RL values in each of them.

Comment: I just needed to make the value a string {{aggregate( layer:= 'Point_Clip', aggregate:='concatenate', expression:=to_string(RL), concatenator:=', ', filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)) )}} -works but doesn't have the start/end value consistently. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329482/get-value-from-point-layer-based-on-start-end-of-line-layer

Comment: thanks to complete my answer with your comment!

Answer (score 3):

> Tested on QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.4

If you are not considering only functions in the Attribute Table I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have 10 features in `"points"` (lila), four in `"lines"` (green), accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following Query, it is possible to achieve the result

```sql
WITH start_data AS (
SELECT l.id AS line_id_start, p.x AS x
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
),

end_data AS (
SELECT l.id AS line_id_end, p.y AS y
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(end_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
)

SELECT l.*, start_data.x, end_data.y
FROM lines AS l
JOIN start_data ON l.id = line_id_start
JOIN end_data ON l.id=line_id_end
```

[image: output]

The output Virtual Layer will give lines where exists an intersection between lines and points, including attributes inherited from snapped points to the ending/starting points of lines.

---

Based on the data set provided by @GeorgeC, the query will look like

```sql
WITH start_data AS (
SELECT l."GID_New" AS line_id_start, p."RL_of_Lid" AS startd
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
),

end_data AS (
SELECT l."GID_New" AS line_id_end, p."RL_of_Lid" AS endd
FROM points AS p
JOIN lines AS l ON st_intersects(end_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
)

SELECT l.*, start_data.startd, end_data.endd
FROM lines AS l
JOIN start_data ON l."GID_New" = line_id_start
JOIN end_data ON l."GID_New" = line_id_end
```

Comment: thanks - I have tried but am having some issues. Please see updated question.