# Get value from point layer based on start/end of line layer

Tags: qgis

I need to get a value from a point table based on the end/start point of a line. This is similar to my question [QGIS Field Calculator Aggregation with a intersect query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329135/qgis-field-calculator-aggregation-with-a-intersect-query)

```
aggregate( layer:= 'Point_Clip', aggregate:='concatenate', expression:=to_string(RL), concatenator:=', ', filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)) )
```

This doesn't always put the start point (based on the direction of the line) and then the end point.

If I get the start/end points using `geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))`

Can I use this to get the value...I was trying something like

```
dbquery('Point_Clip','Name','start_point(@geometry) intersects $geometry')
```

But this gives errors I can't work out. In the end I need it to run in the QGIS Attributes form so that it also fills values from the points at the start/end of existing and new lines using something like

```
if(regexp_substr(aggregate(
layer:= 'Point_Clip',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:= to_string(Name),
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry,
geometry(@parent))),'(.*),')='',geomintersects('Point_Clip','Name'),regexp_substr(aggregate(
layer:= 'Point_Clip',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:= to_string(Name),
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry,
geometry(@parent))),'(.*),'))
```

The test data is only about 20 lines and points - it can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rUV_pAaevs9vATbIsgc9QJvvziRygGN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you seen the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/fill-attribute-table-on-feature-creation-based-on-intersection-with-other-layer/325664#325664)? I think its pretty close to what you want.

Comment: @MBain no I hadn't but that does work as I need it to. Thanks. I'll mark this as a duplicate as it maybe useful for people to find it using the terms I've used.